# JMETER - The string value from the CSV file is sent as array to the URL

Tags: csv, jmeter, parameter-passing

I have the following API URL someexample/Create?Name=${Name} where through POST method in jmeter I send the value of Name from the CSV file.

In the response body the value of Name is [1,2,3,4] instead of User1.

Does anyone have an idea why the correct value defined in the CSV file is not being passed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell what's wrong without seeing:

1. First 2 lines of your CSV file
2. Your [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) setup

If you have i.e. `test.csv` file which looks like:

```
User1
User2
User3
etc.
```

You can configure CSV Data Set Config as follows:

[image]

And refer the variable as `${Name}` where required.

On each iteration each thread (virtual user) will pick up the next line from the file and the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) placeholder will be substituted with data from the CSV in the runtime.

Also you can observe all JMeter Variables with their respective values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination

[image]

More information: [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)